# How can I give increments of one to a variable based on the date and store it?

Tags: java, android

I have a variable (integer) named i.

```
private int i = 0;
```

Now I want to go give it increments of 1 (**i**++) based on the day, meaning that by each day that passes **i** increases by one.
For example, today is day 05/06/2018, in the day 05/08/2018 **i** is going to be equal to 61 (because there are 61 days past the 05/06/2018)

In order for the **i** to remember his current state after the app is closed, I want to store it in shared preferences.

This is what I want to do but I have no idea how.

Some help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that. Just store the `creationDate` and in any point in the future you can get the number of days by subtracting : `newDate - creationDate` and take the number of days.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I've made something similar to what you suggested.